# Anaconda Navigator does not Start on Mac

Tags: anaconda, navigator

I have MacPro (M1 chip) Monterrey (12.2.1)
I tried to launch Navigator but got an error. I have never had such an error before:

```python
Navigator Error
An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up

Report
Please report this issue in the anaconda issue tracker

Main Error
failed to run: 'conda info --json': "FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')"
Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/internal/conda_api.py", line 68, in _call_conda
    (p, stdout_lines, stderr_lines) = streaming_popen.popen(cmd_list,
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/internal/streaming_popen.py", line 83, in popen
    p = logged_subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/internal/logged_subprocess.py", line 27, in Popen
    return subprocess.Popen(args=args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1706, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'conda'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/exceptions.py", line 72, in exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py", line 146, in start_app
    window = run_app(splash)
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py", line 65, in run_app
    window = MainWindow(splash=splash)
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.api = AnacondaAPI()
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 1534, in AnacondaAPI
    ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 84, in __init__
    self._project_api = ProjectAPI()
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/project_api.py", line 161, in ProjectAPI
    PROJECT_API = _ProjectAPIWrapper()
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/project_api.py", line 62, in __init__
    from anaconda_project.api import AnacondaProject
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/api.py", line 24, in 
    from anaconda_project import prepare, project, provide, project_ops
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/prepare.py", line 19, in 
    from anaconda_project.internal import conda_api
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/internal/conda_api.py", line 626, in 
    _default_platforms_with_current = tuple(sorted(list(set(default_platforms + (current_platform(), )))))
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/internal/conda_api.py", line 622, in current_platform
    conda_info = info()
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/internal/conda_api.py", line 117, in info
    return _call_and_parse_json(['info', '--json'], platform=platform)
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/internal/conda_api.py", line 104, in _call_and_parse_json
    out = _call_conda(extra_args, json_mode=True, platform=platform)
  File "/Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_project/internal/conda_api.py", line 73, in _call_conda
    raise CondaError("failed to run: %r: %r" % (command_in_errors, repr(e)))
anaconda_project.internal.conda_api.CondaError: failed to run: 'conda info --json': "FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')"
```

CONDA LIST CONDA

## packages in environment at /Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3:

## Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

_anaconda_depends         2020.07                  py38_0
anaconda                  custom                   py38_1
anaconda-client           1.10.0           py38hecd8cb5_0
anaconda-navigator        2.0.4                    py38_0
anaconda-project          0.11.0           py38hecd8cb5_0
conda                     4.13.0           py38hecd8cb5_0
conda-build               3.21.8           py38h50d1736_0    conda-forge
conda-content-trust       0.1.3            py38hecd8cb5_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-package-handling    1.8.1            py38hca72f7f_0
conda-repo-cli            1.0.5            py38hecd8cb5_0
conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1

Conda INFO

```
 active environment : base
active env location : /Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3
        shell level : 1
   user config file : /Users/tolynovik/.condarc
```

populated config files : /Users/tolynovik/.condarc
conda version : 4.13.0
conda-build version : 3.21.8
python version : 3.8.8.final.0
virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
__unix=0=0
__archspec=1=x86_64
base environment : /Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3  (writable)
conda av data dir : /Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/etc/conda
conda av metadata url : None
channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
package cache : /Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
/Users/tolynovik/.conda/pkgs
envs directories : /Users/tolynovik/opt/anaconda3/envs
/Users/tolynovik/.conda/envs
platform : osx-64
user-agent : conda/4.13.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.8.8 Darwin/21.3.0 OSX/10.16
UID:GID : 501:20
netrc file : None
offline mode : False

Comment: Is the command `conda` recognized in your terminal?

Comment: @FlyingTeller - yes, it does. I ran "conda update conda" and it worked fine

Comment: Could you please add some version info to the question? E.g., output from `conda list conda` should be sufficient. A `conda info` output could also be helpful.

Comment: "*never had such an error before*" - as in, this particular installation used to work, but has stopped working? or that on *previous systems* you never encountered this?

Comment: @merv - added both outputs. It always worked fine but after conda update conda it generated this error.

Comment: Please format your question (downvoted until fixed).

Answer (score 5):

I found this on the anaconda website:

"The current ARM64 installer for macOS does not install Anaconda Navigator. After you have completed the Anaconda Distribution install process for your M1/M2 Mac, you will need to install Navigator separately using your command line interface. Open your Terminal application, type conda install anaconda-navigator, and press Enter. For more information, see Troubleshooting. We are addressing this issue in our next installer release."

Using that command in the terminal fixed it for me.

TL;DR

conda install anaconda-navigator

Comment: It did not fix my problem. I think the path is simply missing. Thus. It is ether a complete re-install or a launching notebook from the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I solved by:

conda deactivate
conda update anaconda-navigator

Now it is working. I do not know why it did not

Comment: I ended up doing a complete install of Anaconda. A few lessons to share.

Comment: I ended up doing a complete install of Anaconda. A few lessons to share. 1. Avoid using pip install in Anaconda. There is always an option to do a conda install with various channels. It seems that "pip install" (while a lot faster) tends to create inconsistencies later. 2. do conda update conda frequently when adding a new package. Do not install multiple packages in one statement. 3. Do not try the flexible installation. It created a lot of problems for me with time. Try to find the current conda way to install the package.